# PHP ftp_put warning filename cannot be empty

Tags: php, ftp

I have a home FTP server. I made a little file uploader for that.

index.php:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_file.php" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
      Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

upload_file.php:

```
<?php

$ftp_server = "192.168.0.11";
$ftp_username   = "";
$ftp_password   =  "";

// setup of connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Pogreska tijekom spajanja.");

// login
if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_password))
{
  echo "Spojen kao $ftp_username@$ftp_server\n";
}
else
{
  echo "Pogreska tijekom spajanja $ftp_username\n";
}

$file = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"];
$remote_file_path = "/KUCNI_FTP-506D-ADD5/".$file;
ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file_path, $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"], FTP_ASCII);
echo "\n\nconnection closed";

?>
```

And I get this error:

> Warning: ftp_put(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\ftp\upload_file.php on line 22

I tried to fix it, but it is not working. Please help me.
EDIT(And sorry for a little bit of Croatian...)

Comment: Why do you use 'name' at one point and 'tmp_name' at the other?

Comment: Why do you supress the errors here: `@ftp_login`? Ftp_login returns true or false. What errors are you trying to avoid?

Comment: Where do you see that?

Comment: I am trying to avoid "Warning: ftp_put(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\ftp\upload_file.php on line 22".

Comment: Below the else you have one line starting with $file and the other with ftp_put. If you suppress a warning that filename can't be empty are you really surprised the code does not work?

Comment: Did you even check, if you receive any value in `$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]`?

Comment: Nope, I do not get values.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at `MAX_FILE_SIZE`, that's an option which is often ignored.

Make sure the file you're trying to upload is within the limits of what you previously defined.